# 3 AGM batteries in parallel; does it matter what battery they are charged from

Tags: batteries, charging

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft7sde.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have 3 AGM 12v batteries in parallel.  Between Battery 1 and 2 I have a BlueSea SI-ACR Automatic Charging Relay - 12/24V DC 120A; I also have an anderson pole connector (SB175) on the last battery3.

I want to hook up a battery charger to the system.

Should I be doing this @ battery1 acting as the alternator does; or Battery2 since the ACR has already cut power between 1-2 (woundn't this unbalance the charging) or on Battery 3 where I have the anderson pole connector (this is where Iwould prefer to connect the charger though Isuspect this will only balance 2-3 and not 1 since it is isolated with the ACR.

diagram
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmOoj1nayk49jcdVgFRUGvoiW9gjig

[image]

Comment: Draw. A. Schematic.

Comment: Are the batteries in series, to make a 36 volt battery bank?  If so, you need a 36 volt charger. Please show a schematic of your system - I can't figure out the connections from your description.

Comment: Sorry my mistake the batteries are wired in parallel.  + to + and - to - throughout.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmOoj1nayk49jcdVgFRUGvoiW9gjig is a link to the diagram

Comment: Colorful, but gibberish. Use the built in schematic editor. Click on edit followed by the schematic symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If the batteries are connected in parallel, you can connect the charger to any battery, and they will all be charged.

Comment: I powered from the 1st battery.  The concern for the 2nd/3rd is that these two batteries would charge but the automatic cutoff between 1 and 2 would prevent the flow back upstream, leading to the three batteries not being in balance.  The 1st battery seemed to do the trick.